# Python: requests: post: basic authorization

Tags: python, post, python-requests, authorization

I have a python function that takes takes in arguments and posts to an api endpoint using requests and basic authorization.The post works fine in Postman; but, in python, I get a 401 error(authentication failed). Below is my code:

```
    request_body = '{"account": "%s"' % token
    request_body += ', "expiry": "%s"'% expiry_mmyy
    request_body += ', "name": "%s"' % name
    request_body += ', "merchid": "%s"' % auth_merchant_id
    request_body += ', "amount": "%s"' % amount
    request_body += ', "tokenize": "y" '
    request_body += ', "orderId": "%s"' % reference_number
    request_body += ', "capture": "y"}'
    
    json_string = json.dumps(request_body)
    #commented this line out and it started working
    #json_string = json_string[1:-1]
    
    logger.info('JSON Request: %s' % json_string)
    logger.info('Username: %s' % AUTH_USER)
    logger.info('Password: %s' % AUTH_PASSWORD)

    http_headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length": str(len(json_string)),
        "Authorization": "Basic"
    }
    
    ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

    #response = requests.post(url=CC_URL, headers=http_headers, data=json_string, auth=("%s" % AUTH_USER, "%s" % AUTH_PASSWORD))
    #response = requests.post(url=CC_URL, headers=http_headers, data=json_string, auth=('testing','testing123'))

    #response = requests.post(CC_URL, verify=False, headers=http_headers, data={json_string}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("%s" % AUTH_USER,"%s" % AUTH_PASSWORD))
    response = requests.post(url=CC_URL, headers=http_headers, data=json_string, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('testing', 'testing123'))


    if response.status_code == 200:
        logger.info('POST Success (HTTP code 200)')
        #response_string = response.json
        response_string = response.text
        logger.info('JSON Response: %s' % response_string)
        logger.info(response_string['resptext'])
        logger.info(response_string['authcode'])        
    else:
        logger.info("Error Code %s" % response.status_code)
```

I am not sure the basic authentication is working. Any help is appreciated.

It could be the TLS1.2 issue; I am not sure as to how to pass the context to requests.post?

Installed version of python is 2.7 with ssl version being 1.0.2k.

Thanks

EDIT:
I tried testing it out using urllib2.urlopen and I still get the same error. I contacted the other end people and they said, their logs show that the http headers are missing. And also, he cannot see the target URL.

Comment: we do mind the indention and so should you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the line:
json_string = json_string[1:-1]

I commented this line out and it started working

Answer (score 1):

You do not must pass the "Authorization": "Basic" part as header. Just the auth=HTTPBasicAuth('testing', 'testing123') part on requests.post()

Comment: Tried that, still, 401 error. The issue seems to be that http headers are missing on the other end.